# How can I replace {{username}} token with actual value while connecting app in Zapier

Tags: zapier, zapier-cli

I created an APP using Zapier CLI and implemented oauth2 authentication. I connected successfully but it shows my app name like this

```
Zapier Test (0.1.0) {{username}}
--------------------------------
{{username}} added 27 minutes ago, used in 0 Zaps
```

I don't want this token here, I want to replace it with username or email ID.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the connection label like this in your authentication.js file.

`connectionLabel: "{{username}}"`

`username` key must come from your test OAuth API

If you test API returns data in hierarchy order like this

```
{
  data: {
    email: stack@example.com
  }
}
```

then use this code `bundle.inputData.data.email`

Read more from [here](https://platform.zapier.com/quickstart/auth), see 
below image if you are using UI.

[image]